# why ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 is appended to url?

Tags: gwt

I am using ExtGWT. in development mode we append **?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997** to url. please help what it means and why we should append?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you're running your application in Development Mode, the browser (more precisely: The GWT plugin) needs to connect to a so-called "code server". The "gwt.codesvr" part is evaluated by that plugin, so it knows, how to connect to that code server.

The job of the code server is to emulate the JavaScript behaviour of the final code. It runs your client-side Java code, which is compiled to class files, but not yet to JavaScript files. This is a) a lot faster than compiling to JavaScript, and b) it allows you to use a Java debugger for the (emulated) client side code.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply. why we always use 127.0.0.1:9997. what this IP indicates?

Comment: @user755806: The default IP address for code servers is usually "127.0.0.1", and the default port is usually "9997". You can change these values when you start your server - are you using Eclipse/NetBeans/IDEA/CommandLine/... to start it?

Comment: @user755806: Then look into "Run > Run Configurations", select your GWT application, and then the "GWT" tab. Here you can configure the "Code Server Port".

Comment: Hi Chris, now i got it. i have one more doubt. please clarify me. i need to upload an excel file and read the contents of the excel file. in ExtGWT how can we achieve this?

Comment: This way of debugging GWT is getting deprecated. Using GWT new "Super Dev" mode, you no longer need to add this URL parameter, but instead click an "Dev mode on" bookmarklet. This will allow you to trigger re-compilation of Java-to-Javascript and sent the result back to the browser, where you'll be able to debug Java lines of code (but JS inspections) through the source maps that has been sent alongside.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the default port for localhost, you could do `gwt.codesvr=localhost:9997`, 9997 is the default port on which the gwt plugin is listening for in eclipse.