# GWT client debugging with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-indigo

I have a GWT application which i need to debug the both client java classes (GWT) and server business classes. I can successfully debug the server side classes where the debug point hits when ever a service request process.

But the problem is in client java classes non of the debug points are hit. What is the reason for it? Do i need to have further steps or tool in order to debug the GWT java classes?

I am using eclipse indigo and glassfish.

Comment: Did you run it using the Debug menu on eclipse (Debug as web application) ?

Comment: yes.Debug is working only for server side java components

Comment: I've never had to do anything special to enable debug on the client side with Eclipse ... how did you create the project, and how did you run the project in debug mode?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to debug the code in development mode [you have to add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038322/why-gwt-codesvr-127-0-0-19997-is-appended-to-url) the *query parameter to the url.*

**Launching your hostpage may be in Two ways.**

**If you are launching your `host page`(`appName.html`) directly from IDE**(eclipse):

Url in browser should be

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

------^---------|appname.html?--------^---------
```

1st part is `local host`

2nd part is your host page

3rd part is debug query parameter.

**If you are dispatching the page from servlet:**

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/appName.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997")
                                                    .forward(request, response);
```

And check your debug cofiguration Arguments tab.

```
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" 
-startupUrl projectname.html -logLevel INFO 
-codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -war
E:\workspace\ProjectName\war com.test.Projectname
```

Refer the link for the [full setup](http://ui-programming.blogspot.in/2010/02/gwt-configure-devmode-port-and.html).

Comment: so you mean i have to insert code specially only for debug purpose?

Comment: Nothing related to code just that query parameter in the url to debug.