# How to manually test compiled GWT project?

Tags: java, gwt

I am brand new to GWT. I followed the official tutorials, but on the [Compilation section](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/compile.html), I am getting completely confused by this:

> Tip: If you launched the development mode server, you can run your application in production mode (after compiling it) by removing the gwt.codesvr parameter from the URL before loading the application.

I don't see this `gwt.codesvr` parameter anywhere, either in build.xml or in the devmode UI. What is meant by this? How can I test the compiled version of the application locally?

Comment: See [why ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 is appended to url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038322/why-gwt-codesvr-127-0-0-19997-is-appended-to-url).

Comment: I have created a minimal alternative guide for modern GWT, I think currently the easiest way to use GWT is using maven, and this is how to start with https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that parameter either.

I think the best way to start with GWT using Eclipse is by using the Eclipse plugin from branflake.

https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

On this github page a link is presented "GWT Eclipse Plugin Youtube Playlist". Follow that link and watch the videos. You will probably learn a lot from them.

Answer (score 0):

When you run devmode, by default the codeserver will be on port 9997.  You don't need the `gwt.codesvr=...` parameter in the URL unless you are doing something special.

When you start devmode, either from the command line, or in an IDE (eclipse), the launch URL that is given does not have this parameter in it.  The documentation you refer to would relate to an earlier version of GWT I assume, and is a little out of date.